# Designing react- reducer of a social site

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I have three different components in my app.
ie. 1. Newsfeed (here i am fetching all the posts)
    2. Trending (posts with of popular hashtags)
    3. UserProfile (fetching all the posts of that user)

```
const postReducer = (state = postReducerDefaultState, action) => {
switch(action.type){
    case 'ADD_POST':{
        return[
             action.post,
             ...state
         ]
    }
     case 'FIND_POST':
        return action.post 
    case 'REMOVE_POST':
        return state.filter(post => post._id !== action.id)
    case 'EDIT_POST':
        return state.map(post => {
            if (post._id === action.id){
               return{
                   ...post,
                   ...action.updates
               };
            }else{
                return post;
            }
        });
    case 'LIKE_POST':
       return state.map(post => {
           if(post._id === action.id){
               return{
                  ...post,
                  likes:[...post.likes,action.likedBy]     
               }
           }else{
               return post;
           }
       });
    case 'UNLIKE_POST':
        return state.map(post => {
            if(post._id === action.id){
                return {
                    ...post,
                    likes : post.likes.filter(liker => liker !== 
 action.likedBy)
                }

            }else{
                return post;
            }
        })   
    case 'ADD_COMMENT':
       return state.map(post => {
           if(post._id === action.pid){
               return{
                   ...post,
                   comments:[...post.comments,action.comment]
               }
           }else{
               return post;
           }
       });
    case 'SET_POST':
          return action.posts;
    case 'HASHTAG_POST':
          return action.posts;           
    default:
          return state;        
}
};
```

in this design if i go from one component to other component, (dashboard to trending), I lost all the data of the dashboard. But if want to keep the like,comment functionalty for dashboard and trending posts, then i have to write the like-comment functionality separately for all the mentioned three components. This approach will work, but i am not satisfied with as i have to write same thing thrice. Can anyone suggest the best approach?

Comment: Are you talking about adding the same functionality to multiple React components?

Comment: yes. All the like-comments functionality

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The recommended way to solve this problem is with [higher order components](https://reactjs.org/docs/higher-order-components.html), which are React components that "wrap" another component to provide common functionality. You should be able to find plenty of resources explaining this, but a typical higher order component looks something like this:

```
import React from 'react';

const higherOrderComponent = (WrappedComponent) => 
{
  class HOC extends React.Component {
    render() {
      return <WrappedComponent />;
    }
  }

  return HOC;
};
```

You can then add whatever functionality needs to be shared to the higher order component. Then, you can use it something like this:

```
const SimpleHOC = higherOrderComponent(MyComponent);
```

EDIT: If you want the same functionality to apply for different reducer actions, that's straightforward. Just have the same callback fall through for different cases, as in this example:

```
case 'ACTION_1':
case 'ACTION_2':
case 'ACTION_3':
    // callback here
```

For your application, it will be something like this:

```
case 'EDIT_POST':
case 'LIKE_POST':
case 'UNLIKE_POST':
    return state.map(post => {
        if (post._id === action.id){
           return{
               ...post,
               ...action.updates
           };
        }else{
            return post;
        }
    });
```

Comment: In my case those like-comment functionality is in reducer which is not a react Component. So I don't think hoc is useful here.

Comment: Have amended my answer.

Comment: Sorry. I have not understood that how will I use this in my case

Comment: Yes. Thanks for the help